# What's the meaning of *abs* in URLs of arxiv.org

Tags: publications, journals, arxiv

On every paper I read, the URL-path contains *abs* before the ID of the paper. I mostly read about machine learning if that matters.
Does it mean *abs*tract? Or *abs*olute path?

See the example: [image: example].

Comment: The question is off-topic, but presumably short for abstract, since it links to the abstract page of the preprint.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia SE. Sorry, but only the developers at arXiv can answer about how they chose to implement the repository. In any case, for any standard user of arXiv, the meaning assigned to the path is irrelevant.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I think we actually can answer this by referencing arXiv's public documentation, see the "URLs for standard arXiv functions" section at https://arxiv.org/help/arxiv_identifier_for_services But maybe it's still off topic?

Comment: The relevant "case law" for questions about arXiv, etc., seems to be [this](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2220). So, seems like the on-topic-ness of this question comes down to whether we consider the meaning of "abs" to be related to academia, versus related to arXiv's internal software engineering.